# Create similar iOS apps reusing almost everything (with Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, reusability

I want to make multiple apps which share the same structure and code, but have different images, fonts, names and urls.

I would like a simple way to make this apps without replicating the whole project, so that when I find a bug I'll have to correct it only once.

Thank you.

PS: It isn't important the language (Objective-C or Swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create multiple targets within the same project. You can then include or exclude asset catalogues, configuration JSON files etc. on a per-target basis. If you're consistent with the names this should get you most of the way there. You can also look at target-specific build flags or constants.

Comment: Thank's for the answer.. I'm not sure if it is a good solution for a great number of apps, but I'll try..